# AccountManager and OAuth - how to add account?

Tags: android, oauth, accountmanager

My application connects with the server, which uses OAuth authorization.
How should I store such accounts in Account Manager?
In case I have login and pass, it can look like below:

```
        Account account = new Account("user1", context.getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
        if (am.addAccountExplicitly(account, "pass1", null)) {
            result = new Bundle();
            Log.i(TAG, "account: "+account.name+", "+account.type);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            activity.setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
```

But what should be passed instead of user name and pass in case of OAuth-account?
And where should I store OAuth-secret? OAuth token should be stored in KEY_AUTHTOKEN?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the password you could `setAuthToken`, put the OAuth token there instead:

> It's important to understand that AccountManager is not an encryption service or a keychain. It stores account credentials just as you pass them, in plain text. On most devices, this isn't a particular concern, because it stores them in a database that is only accessible to root. But on a rooted device, the credentials would be readable by anyone with adb access to the device.
>
> With this in mind, you shouldn't pass the user's actual password to AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(). Instead, you should store a cryptographically secure token that would be of limited use to an attacker. If your user credentials are protecting something valuable, you should carefully consider doing something similar.

- http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html